# PowerBuilder: DBMS DIR is not supported in your current installation

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I am working on a migration project, where we are migrating one 32-bit PB12.0 application from Windows 2003 to 2012 server. We have copied all the required files and folders in the new server. Sybase Open Client has been installed and using ISQL we are able to connect to Sybase DB. We have not change anything in the PB12.0 code we just copied the .exe and referenced DLL in the new server.

While executing the job we are getting

**DBMS DIR is not supported in your current installation**

But if we navigate to the PB folder we can see PBDIR120.DLL is there.

Comment: What code do you use for the connection to the database? Do you use an .INI file? Is the .INI file accessible?

Comment: Yes @EduardoG. we are using INI file for DB connection and its confirmed that, the job able to read the INI file.If the job is not able to read the INI file then it is throwing "DBMS  is not supported in your current installation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue got resolved. The reason of the issue,

Previously, PB12.0 job was using Sybase Open Client OCS_12_5. As part of windows migration, Sybase Open Client is upgraded to OCS_15_0. Because of this there was a conflict between PBDIR120.DLL and the dlls under **"OCS_15_0/dll" folder**.

If we add the DLLs in the path from **"OCS_12_5/dll" folder** then the application is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a path variable to the directory. I had some simmilar issues ( with PB12.6 ) and this helped.